# View distorted after connecting two scenes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have the following problem:

In my game, I have two scenes (GameScene.swift and GameOverScene.swift). I think they are pretty self-explanatory, in GameScene.swift happens everything connected to the game and if the player collides with the enemy, he will be sent to GameOverScene.swift. This is the code:

```
        var transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        var gameOverScene:SKScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, dead: true)
        self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: transition)
```

As soon as the player touches the screen, he should be redirected to the GameScene:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        var transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        var scene:SKScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)

    }

}
```

Unfortunately, everything in the GameOverScene.swift is completely distorted and the background color changes (?!). When going back to GameScene.swift, it's distorted as well. This is how GameOverScene.swift is initialized:

```
class GameOverScene: SKScene {

    init(size:CGSize, dead:Bool) {
        super.init(size: size)
```

Any idea why this doesn't work properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? “distorted” is pretty vague.

Comment: For comparison: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3887/ve8kobok_png.htm

Comment: check scene.scaleMode

Comment: @rakeshbs: always (1024.0, 768.0), no matter if distorted or not. I'm using the iPhone 6 Simulator.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: What exactly do u mean? I'm kind of a newbie

Comment: I just added the following to GameScene.swift (in didMoveToView) and GameOverScene (below the initialization):         scene?.scaleMode = .AspectFill        now the size is right, but the background color still changes... any idea why?